# gjs GIRepository how to know which string to identify the exact typelib

Tags: gjs

I read about the architecture of Gobject introspection.
On one side i have a .so dynamic library, on the other side i have a gir file (some sort of xml file) for javascript bindings, which leads to the compiled typelib file.

Most of my typelib files are in the directory /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0
for example WebKit2-4.0.typelib.

how do i know, that i have to use, (where are the definitions?)

`const Webkit=imports.gi.WebKit2;`

because i tried

`const Webkit=imports.gi["WebKit2-4.0"];` or
`const Webkit=imports.gi.WebKit;`

if i use imports.gi  , gjs searches for a typelib file. The directories where it searches, i can get with
`const Gir=imports.gi.GIRepository; log (Gir.Repository.get_search_path());`

for other ids then 'gi', imports[directory][...][filename], it searches in the directories defined in the array imports.searchPath for a Javascript file, right?

last problem - the references on gjs page: there are a lot of functions, which exists in the references, but then are not available. Are there any other good references outthere, with examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do i know, that i have to use, (where are the definitions?)

Probably the easiest way to find a GIR import name you don't know is by browsing the [API Documentation](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org), such as for [`WebKit2`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/webkit240). Of course, you'll have to have the appropriate packages installed for those libraries.

> for other ids then 'gi', imports[directory][...][filename], it searches in the directories defined in the array imports.searchPath for a Javascript file, right?

Yes, the `imports.searchPath` array is for JavaScript sources. You can read about those imports in the GJS [project documentation](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/-/blob/master/doc/Modules.md#legacy-imports).

> the references on gjs page: there are a lot of functions, which exists in the references, but then are not available. Are there any other good references outthere, with examples?

You'd have to be clearer about which GJS page you're looking at and which functions. Below are some links to documentation for GJS:

- [gjs.guide](https://gjs.guide) (Tutorials, topic-specific guides, tips and examples)
- [GJS Project Documentation](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/-/tree/master/doc) (Documentation about GJS itself)
- [API Documentation](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org) (Documentation for introspected C libraries)

We also have Matrix channels for GJS where you can ask for help:

- https://matrix.to/#/#javascript:gnome.org (JavaScript)
- https://matrix.to/#/#extensions:gnome.org (GNOME Shell Extensions)

Comment: thx for the answer, when i open https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/girepository20~2.0_api/ there is a class listed GIRepository.Repository, so I imported the GIRepository to Gir, but if i do a check with Object.getOwnPropertyNames, which lists all enumerable and non enumerable properties on an Object, i get a Null Str. I followed the whole prototype chain of Gir, no Repository function found, although it exists on GIR, why? 
JS:  let Gir=imports.gi.GIRepository; Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Gir); 
returns Null Str.

Comment: but JS: Object.getOwnPropertyNames (Gir.Repository);
returns 'prototype,$gtype,dump,error_quark,get_default,get_option_group,get_search_path,prepend_library_path,prepend_search_path,length,name'.  the prototype of the Repository function and some static functions defined on it.
 i want to know which properties (functions, objects, properties) exists on an object. but its seems its not reliable, following the prototype chain.

Comment: The classes and members in introspected libraries are not (immediately) enumerable, probably for performance reasons. Some libraries may have quite a few members, so they will only be available in that sense *after* they are accessed. The members you see listed there have no doubt already been called internally by the time your script is run.

Comment: you are right. JS:  let Gir = imports.gi.GIRepository, dummy=Gir.Repository;
log (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Gir));
returns JS log: Repository
okay that means, i have to read the references and manually check which functions, properties, objects exists. thanx!